# I do not want to click twice to trigger an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am devloping a website in which I have created an option to upload multiple images using plupload script. Which allows us to trigger a popup when we click on an image to upload mulitple images.

This script requires a JS file to be added which has a function started with the code as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var baseurl = $('#baseurl').val();
var i = 0;
$('.uploadFiles_one').click(function(){

   $('#uploadBox_one').dialog('open');
    return false
})
....
..some more js code..
....
})
```

Now I have modified this JS file so that I would be able to use the same JS file for multiple DOM element in which I have generated via PHP loop, the new script with the code as below:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".uploadFiles_loop", function(){
var baseurl = $('#baseurl').val();
var i = 0;
var my_id = $(this).attr('id');
var cnt = my_id.replace("anchor_", "");

$('.uploadFiles_loop').click(function(){

   $('#uploadBox_'+cnt).dialog('open');
    return false;
});
....
..some more js code..
....
})
```

The front end would have one Image when any user click on the image it will open a popup. But now when  I have modified the script I have to click twice on the image to get the popup. But after that all the rest Image uploader icons got open in single click.

So my question is why I have to click any "Upload Image" twice first time( I mean when the page has been loaded).

Comment: Hint: How many click handlers have you bound in the second code block?

Comment: What is happening is that the first time you click is is executing the function, which includes applying the click handler. The second time you are clicking it executing the click handler. I'll explain better in my answer.

Comment: @nnnnnn - exactly what I was going for

Answer (score 4):

Try to remove this extra click handler `$('.uploadFiles_loop').click(function(){`...`});`

Leaving just:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".uploadFiles_loop", function(){
    var baseurl = $('#baseurl').val();
    var i = 0;
    var my_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var cnt = my_id.replace("anchor_", "");
    $('#uploadBox_'+cnt).dialog('open');
    // Recheck were you want this return false;
    return false; 
....
..some more js code..
....
})
```

On your code you had a listener that on click run a function that added a click listener. So only by second click it would run the code `$('#uploadBox_'+cnt).dialog('open'); return false;`. If you remove that it will run on first click.

P.s. - On your code you have a `return false;`, if you have more code after it will not work. So I commented it, you might want it after the rest of you code you have.

Comment: @kralco626, I normally am slower. Got lucky this time :)

Comment: @remyabel - ya, this is why I'm saying I'm not sure what he is trying to accomplish, I was wondering the same thing. In all likelyhood he would want to remove the code outside the on function, but idk what the code does... haha

Comment: @remyabel, good point. The OP didn't show more code, so let's see what he answers.

Comment: @All - of course, if history is any indication of future actions, we wont hear back from him and he wont accept an answer :), so we'll proly just have to live with never knowing :P

Comment: Doesn't return false stop the normal click action from function or propagating? Or something like that?

Comment: @kralco626, yes, if there are more `.uploadFiles_loop` he will need that, but maybe later in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I have already did the same what you have suggested in the above code and it was not working. See the code below that I have used to do so.

$( document ).on( "click", ".uploadFiles_loop", function(){
var baseurl = $('#baseurl').val();
var i = 0;
var my_id = $(this).attr('id');
var cnt = my_id.replace("anchor_", "");

//$('.uploadFiles_loop').click(function(){

   $('#uploadBox_'+cnt).dialog('open');
  //  return false;
//});
....
..some more js code..
....
})

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( document ).on( "click", ".uploadFiles_loop", function(){
        var baseurl = $('#baseurl').val();
        var i = 0;
        var my_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var cnt = my_id.replace("anchor_", "");

        $('#uploadBox_'+cnt).dialog('open');
        return false;


    });
    ....
    ..some more js code..
    ....
});
```

Very very unclear what you are trying to actually accomplish, however, you need to put the action you want to happen when you click, DIRECTLY IN the `on` function. Don't wrap it in another click function